# Disabling a Second GPU?

Tags: nvidia, ati, graphics, hardware, 14.04

I have both an AMD ( HD 7850 ) and an Nvidia ( 8400 GS ) GPU installed on my motherboard.

The Nvidia card is only there because of its S-video port, which I use to output to my old'n'bulky CRT TV. I have no need of it in Ubuntu, and things seem to get fussy at times because of its presence.

I was wondering if there was any way to make Ubuntu ignore its existence. I know that it's possible to disable the Nvidia GPU in Windows via the device manager, but I've so far been unable to find a similar method in Ubuntu. Any ideas?

Please let me know if there is any other information that I should provide :)

System specs:

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04
- Motherboard: GA-990FXA-UD3 rev 1.1 F9 bios
- CPU: AMD Phenom II x4 965 BE
- GPU 1: AMD Radeon HD 7850
- GPU 2: Nvidia 8400 GS
- SPU: Creative Audigy 4 - Sound Blaster

Answer (score 0):

You will have to uninstall the Nvidia drivers, assuming you've previously installed them:

1. Determine what packages you need to uninstall with:

   ```
   $ dpkg --get-selections | grep -i nvidia
   ```
2. `sudo apt-get purge` them.

Note: `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*` should also work.

Now, I believe that in order to make sure your Nvidia card isn't used at all by Linux, you will have to blacklist the nouveau driver. You can do so as **SU**:

(note: omit the `#` character)

```
# echo -e "\n\n# Manually blacklisted nouveau so as to ensure Nvidia card is disabled\nblacklist nouveau" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```